# How can I select top 25 customers ordered by amount descending, for each dept?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I want top 25 customers ordered by amount descending, for each dept. like:

```
Dept|Customer|Amt

    1 cust_1 5000
      cust_2 2000
        .
        .
        .
    2 cust_26 6000
      cust_27 3000
        .
        .
    3
    .
    .
    7
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Amount] } ON COLUMNS ,

NON EMPTY { 

[Customer].[DEPT].[DEPT]*

ORDER( 

TOPCOUNT([Customer].[Customer].[Customer],25,[Measures].[Amount]),

[Measures].[Amount], DESC)

}

FROM [cube]
```

I am getting result but not like 25 for each dept, though I have proper data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second term of the cross join for the rows (`ORDER(TOPCOUNT(...))`) is not aware of the first (`[Customer].[DEPT].[DEPT]`). You should use [`Generate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145526.aspx) for this, as it loops over the departments, and thus allows you to put the current department into the first argument of the `TOPCOUNT`:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Amount] } ON COLUMNS ,
NON EMPTY
Generate([Customer].[DEPT].[DEPT],
         TOPCOUNT({[Customer].[DEPT].CURRENTMEMBER}
                  *
                  [Customer].[Customer].[Customer],
                  25,
                  [Measures].[Amount]
                 )
        )
FROM [cube]
```

Also note that you do not need to order the result of `TOPCOUNT` descending, [it is already ordered this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx).

Comment: Perfect. I also found the same at same time. Thanks. Thanks for the explanation also.